# Pointer is showing on the wrong screen

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, xorg, mouse-pointer

### Tl;dr

I have a 3 monitor setup and when I move the pointer to the right side of the screen on my left monitor it actually shows in the middle of the screen on the middle monitor.

### Setup:

[image: Screen layout]

- DVI-I-2-2: 1920x1080
- DVI-I-1-1: 2560x1440 Primary
- DP-2: 1920x1080

I am using a USB-C Triple-4K Dock from Displaylink to connect the monitors to my Thinkpad L490.

- CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-8565U
- GPU: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2)

When I move the pointer to the right side of DVI-I-2-2 several things happen: On the first pixel of the area shown below the pointer is visible on both DVI-I-2-2 and DVI-I-1-1. Then moving further to the edge of the screen towards DVI-I-1-1 it's an on and off between showing on one or the other but mostly showing on DVI-I-1-1 When tracing the affected area it seems a little bit as if the left screen is inside the middle one.
[image: Layout affected areas]

I created screenshots with the default gnome screenshot tool and shutter but both only pick up the pointer at the actual position.

I switched to wayland where this issue does not occur. I tried to reset any `xrandr`settings with `xrandr -s 0`.

When configuring the layout with `arandr` it's giving me the following `xrandr` command:

```
xrandr \
        --output eDP-1 --off \
        --output DP-1 --off \
        --output HDMI-1 --off \
        --output DP-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 4480x0 --rotate normal \
        --output HDMI-2 --off \
        --output DVI-I-4-4 --off \
        --output DVI-I-3-3 --off \
        --output DVI-I-2-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal \
        --output DVI-I-1-1 --primary --mode 2560x1440 --pos 1920x0 --rotate normal
```

Executing it changes nothing. I tried moving DVI-I-2-2 below DVI-I-1-1 but it results in the same effect.

I actually have no idea where this might come from or where to start debugging this behavior so my question is:
**How can I debug (and fix) this behavior?**

Comment: One possibility is using arandr.

Comment: xinput     https://askubuntu.com/search?q=xinput+maptooutput

Comment: @ToDo I updated the question with what I tried with `arandr`. I am not really sure how else it might help me.

Comment: @pierrely what do you think how mapping the input might help? I am using a normal mouse and not a touchpad.

Comment: @Daniel, I have no idea. whilst your issue is not a simple mapping issue, who knows? a simple reboot would undo any changes. I also notice there you have other DVI monitors off, so you might experiment enabling them and disabling the ON ones if possible.    drivers? https://askubuntu.com/search?q=DisplayLink  . scaling issue? https://support.displaylink.com/forums/287786-displaylink-feature-suggestions/suggestions/16077313-fix-linux-driver-scaling